# Getting output from a job

Tags: powershell

I'm failing miserably to get any output from jobs - what is wrong with the following code?

```
$test = {
    DIR
}

$mjob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$test}
while (Get-Job -State Running){}
Receive-Job -Job $mjob -OutVariable $otest

Write-Host($otest)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `-OutVariable` supply only the name of the variable e.g.:

```
... -OutVariable otest
```

unless `$otest` happens to contain the name of the variable you want to save the output to.

A few other suggestions.  `$test` represents a scriptblock so you don't need to put `{}` around it.  And rather than wait using a while loop, just use `Wait-Job` e.g.:

```
$test = { get-childitem }
$job = Start-Job $test
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job -OutVariable otest

$otest
```

Comment: I tried to edit my script to be like yours and it failed. After much messing and step-by-step changing I discovered that putting {} braces around $job = Start-Job {$test} causes it to just do nothing - or at least return nothing (I don't know!). This seems at odds with the official help so hence a bit confused.

Comment: Ok - it must be because putting curly braces means that you are putting actual commands in and no braces is for a variable referencing a code block?

Comment: When you specify `Start-Job -Sriptblock { $test }`, a *new* scriptblock is created and it will evaluate a variable inside the scriptblock named test.  That will evaluate to null, so you'll get no output.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pipeline to wait for the job to finish and then receive its result. Make sure to remove the braces when you pass a scriptblock to the ScriptBlock parameter, otherwise you're creating a nested scriptblock:

```
$test = { DIR }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $test | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```